# JqGrid getRowdata gives cell value on a row as string

Tags: jqgrid

I have an issue with jqGrid 4.6.0 
When I try to get the row data it changes each data to a string I need to parse them to get the actual int or boolean values what is strange is that when I see the rowobject inside a custom formatter the rowdata seems correct

Here is the sample code and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/99/) link for the sample I created

```
  var myformatter = function (cellval, options, rowObject) 
  {
 // rowObject is correct here {id: 1, Name: "test1", IsActive: true, Count: 10}
     var active = rowObject.IsActive;// here active is true/false which is good
     var count = rowObject.Count; // here count is 10,20,30 which is good
     if(active )
     {
      // do what ever
     }
         return cellval;
   }
   var mydata = [
        {id:1, Name: "test1", IsActive: true, Count: 10},
        {id:2, Name: "test2", IsActive: false, Count: 20},
        {id:3, Name: "test2", IsActive: false, Count: 30} ];

        var grid = $("#list").jqGrid({

                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                height: "auto",
              colNames: ['id', 'Name','Is Active','Count'],
                colModel :[
                    {name:'id', index:'id', width:55},
                    {name:'Name', index:'Name', width:90},
                    {name:'IsActive', index:'IsActive', width:90, editable: true ,formatter:myformatter},
                    {name:'Count', index:'Count', width:90, editable: true}

                ],
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                sortname: 'idcustomers',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: 'Customers',
                cellEdit: true,
                cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
                  });
var row = $('#list').jqGrid('getRowData', 1);

// row is: {id: "1", Name: "test1", IsActive: "true", Count: "10"}  
// What I was expecting {id: 1, Name: "test1", IsActive: true, Count: 10}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getLocalRow` method instead of `getRowData` to solve your problem. It's important to understand that `getRowData` get the text from `<td>` element. Thus the standard type of data is always string. The method `getLocalRow` just get the reference to internal element of `data` array with original data.

One more remark: it's recommended to define [unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) (`unformat` callback) formatter always if one defines custom formatter.

One can see that you use editing of data. The standard editing will change the type of data on modification. Thus you will have the same problem as before. Free jqGrid allows to fix the problem by specifying `convertOnSave` callback for the column. See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Editing-of-local-data) article for more details. Additionally free jqGrid support some standard column templates, which simplifies the data conversion for Boolean, integer and numbers. On can add `template: "integer"` property in the `Count` column (see the template definition [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.3/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L138-L145)) and to add `template: "booleanCheckbox"` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.3/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L158-L174)). You can debug [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm) for example and verify that the types of properties of `data` will be hold correctly after editing.

Comment: thanks this worked. Regarding your remarks this is a quick and dirty demo I created for some one like you to answer easily. But my real one is way more complected and have everything it needed regarding unformatting and other stuff.