# getLocalRow gives wrong data after deleting row

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid version 4.6.0
I started using getLocalRow in jqGrid after I asked a question in 
[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471748/jqgrid-getrowdata-gives-cell-value-on-a-row-as-string)

Here is a sample code I prepared When some one clicks a button I delete row2 but when I do ('getLocalRow', 2) it gives me row 3 ? Isn't the rowId param in getLocalRow the rowID of the grid which is the key? getRowData works as expected but I don't want to use that because It gives me everything as a string as noted in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471748/jqgrid-getrowdata-gives-cell-value-on-a-row-as-string) and answered in [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37472318/3038042)

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/125/) is the jsFiddle sample to test.

```
deleteRow = function()
{
   $("#list").jqGrid('delRowData', 2);
   var row2 =   $("#list").jqGrid('getLocalRow', 2);
   var row3 =   $("#list").jqGrid('getLocalRow', 3);

   var row2Corrent =   $("#list").jqGrid('getRowData', 2); // Empty
   var row3correct =   $("#list").jqGrid('getRowData', 3);// gives {id:3, DocGroupName: "name3", DocList: "list3", Mandatory: "No"},
}
            "use strict";
            var mydata = [
                    {id:1, DocGroupName: "name1", DocList: "list1", Mandatory: "Yes"},
                    {id:2, DocGroupName: "name2", DocList: "list2", Mandatory: "No"},
                    {id:3, DocGroupName: "name3", DocList: "list3", Mandatory: "No"},
                    {id:4, DocGroupName: "name4", DocList: "list4", Mandatory: "Yes"},
                ];
            $("#list").jqGrid({


                //url:'php.scripts/customers.get.php',
                //datatype: 'xml',
                //mtype: 'POST',
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                height: "auto",
              colNames: ['id', 'Document Group Name','Document Name','No of Mandatory'],
                colModel :[
                    {name:'id',key:true, index:'id', width:55},
                    {name:'DocGroupName', index:'DocGroupName', width:90, editable: true,edittype: 'select', 
                                            },
                    {name:'DocList', index:'DocList', width:90, editable: true },
                    {name:'Mandatory', index:'Mandatory', width:90, editable: true}

                ],
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                sortname: 'idcustomers',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: 'Customers',
                cellEdit: true,
                cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
                afterSaveCell: function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
                    if(name=='DocGroupName')
                  {
                  var row = $('#list').jqGrid('getRowData',currentRow);     
                   row.DocList='';
                   var row = $('#list').jqGrid('setRowData',currentRow,row);       
                   }
                },
                beforeSaveCell: function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
                 // var row = $("#list").getRowData(rowid);
                   var row = $('#list').jqGrid('getRowData',rowid);
                   currentRow= rowid;

                },

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found to the problem is to use

```
getRowData(rowId);
```

Since getrowdata gives everything as a string I was required to do some data conversions for example

var intValue= parseInt(intField);

When I wanted the id from string or

```
  var trueFalse=  parseBool(boolField);
    function parseBool(val) {
        return val === true || val === "true"
    }
```

When I wanted boolean from string.

It is a bit of extra work but that is the only option I am left of.